# Which cryptocurrencies can you margin trade with bitcoin?

Tags: exchanges, trading, margin

I am trying to compile all cryptocurrencies (and fiat currencies) that can be margin trade with bitcoin. Here is a list of the pairs that I have found so far. If you know others please add them in your answer.

- ADA: Bitmex, Huobi.pro*
- BCH : Bitfinex, Bitmex, Huobi.pro*
- BTG : Bitfinex
- BTN : Huobi.pro*
- BTS : Poloniex
- CLAM : Poloniex
- DASH : Bitfinex, Poloniex, Huobi.pro*
- DOGE : Poloniex
- EDO : Bitfinex
- ELA : Huobi.pro*
- ELF : Huobi.pro*
- EOS : BitMex, Huobi.pro*
- ETC : Bitfinex, Huobi.pro*, Kraken
- ETH : Bitfinex,Bitmex, Poloniex, Huobi.pro*, Kraken
- ETP : Bitfinex
- EUR : Kraken
- FCT : Poloniex
- HSR : Huobi.pro*
- IOAT : Bitfinex
- IOST : Huobi.pro*
- LTC : Bitfinex, Bitmex, Poloniex, Huobi.pro*
- MAID : Poloniex
- NAS : Huobi.pro*
- NEO : Bitfinex
- OMG : Bitfinex, Huobi.pro*
- ONT : Huobi.pro*
- QTUM : Huobi.pro*
- REP : Kraken
- SAN : Bitfinex
- TRX : Huobi.pro*
- USD : Kraken, OKCoin
- XLM : Poloniex (called STR on Poloniex)
- XMR : Bitfinex, Kraken, Poloniex
- XRP : Bitfinex, Bitmex, Poloniex, Huobi.pro*
- ZEC : Bitfinex, Huobi.pro*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't fit our format.

Comment: Could you recommend another place to post it ?

Comment: maybe r/bitcoinmarkets or r/cryptocurrency?